# Algorithm to get "adjacent" values of a list with subsets

Tags: java, algorithm, list, subset

I have a text file like this:

```
A
B
C
```

And each element has a subset like this:

```
A = { a1, a2, a3 }
B = { b1, b2 }
C = { c1, c2, c3 }
```

I want to generate this:

```
    a1, b1, c1
    a2, b1, c1
    a3, b1, c1
    a1, b2, c1
    a1, b1, c2
    a1, b1, c3
```

I don't know the number of elements in the text file (e.g. could be: A, B, C, D, E) and the subsets could vary in size.

All I can think it's a recursive function with 2 indexes, maybe "position in the array" and "index of the array", but I really don't know how to implement all of this.

I even tried to adapt a function that does cartesian product with the same inputs, but I totally failed. **I don't need to generate Cartesian product**.

Comment: What about a combination like `a1, b2, c2` - that is _not_ something you want?

Comment: This doesn't seem like Cartesian product, since there are only 8 outputs? Or what you want to generate really is the Cartesian product?

Comment: I don't have to generate Cartesian product, just tried to adapt that function to my purpose (and I failed as I said). I want these: scan A array leaving the other arrays "unchanged" > when A is at the end, then "pass" at B array and do the same > when B is at the end, then "pass" at C array and do the same, etc...
@cheeken Unfortunately I don't want a combination like this :(

Comment: `a1, b3, c1` ?? I don't understand where b3 came from as it's not listed in your B subset

Comment: Thanks for all the answers... But which solution should I choose? The one posted by John B seems more compact and cheaper in terms of resources... Am I wrong?

Comment: It's up to you. Each solution has its benefits and potential drawbacks~

Comment: @Pierpaolo Compactness is a matter of aesthetics. Being more verbose makes for readability and easier debugging. But you are right: my answer has much worse performance (thanks to `if (!lines.contains(line))`). The `asString(List<String> lines)` method could be replaced by something much more compact if you don't mind using `List.asString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<List<Integer>> myInput = ...

for(int i=0; i<myInput.size(); i++){
     for (int j=0; j<myInput.get(i).size(); j++){
        if (j == 0 && i > 0){
           continue;
        }
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(myInput.size());
        for(int k=0; k<myInput.size(); k++){
            if (k == i){
               result.add(myInput.get(k).get(j));
            }else{
               result.add(myInput.get(k).get(0));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

Loop through all the lists where the index is the list to be iterated.

Find the size of the inner List to be iterated and loop that many time.

Loop through the lists always getting the first element unless the list is the list being indexed, in which case get the next value from the iteration list.

Comment: Shouldn't List<Integer> be List<String> ?

Answer (score 6):

Build the "base list", which is comprised of the first element of every list.  Then loop through all the elements of all of the lists.  For each such element, update the base list at the appropriate position with that element, and add this updated list to a running tally of lists.

I've included an example implementation below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AdjacentListGenerator {
    public static <T> List<List<T>> generateAdjacentLists(List<List<T>> lists) {
        List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        List<T> baseList = new ArrayList<T>();

        // Generate the base list, which is comprised of all the first elements
        for (List<T> list : lists) {
            baseList.add(list.get(0));
        }
        result.add(baseList);

        // Loop over each list, and for each element beyond the first, make a
        // copy of the base list, update that element in place, and add it to
        // our result
        for (int list_i = 0; list_i < lists.size(); list_i++) {
            List<T> list = lists.get(list_i);
            for (int listElement_i = 1; listElement_i < list.size(); listElement_i++) {
                List<T> updatedList = new ArrayList<T>(baseList);
                updatedList.set(list_i, list.get(listElement_i));
                result.add(updatedList);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> a = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a1", "a2", "a3" });
        List<String> b = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "b1", "b2" });
        List<String> c = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "c1", "c2", "c3" });
        List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        lists.add(a);
        lists.add(b);
        lists.add(c);
        for (List<String> list : AdjacentListGenerator
                .generateAdjacentLists(lists)) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[a1, b1, c1]
[a2, b1, c1]
[a3, b1, c1]
[a1, b2, c1]
[a1, b1, c2]
[a1, b1, c3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is using Containers so I will try to solve it only with arrays.

In this algorithm I just print 1st line then I'm focusing on surrounding next elements of subsets by first elements of rest subsets

```
String[] lines = { "a1, a2, a3", "b1, b2", "c1, c2, c3" };

String[][] array = new String[lines.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    array[i] = lines[i].replaceAll(" +", "").split(",");

//lets type 1st row to ignore it in rest algoritm
System.out.print(array[0][0]);
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    System.out.print(", " + array[i][0]);
System.out.println();

//in rest of algorithm we must surround each element by 
//1st element or rest rows, so lets iterate over each row
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
    //and surround its elements
    for (int col = 1; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        //left surround
        int i=0;
        for (; i<row; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i][0]+", ");
        //
        System.out.print(array[row][col]);
        //right surround
        for (i=i+1; i<array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(", "+array[i][0]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes you have already sorted your datasets and they're in the correct order.

```
public class SubsetPrinter
{
  private static final String DELIMITER = ", ";
  private static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

  public static String printSubsets(Map<String, List<String>> elements)
  {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : elements.entrySet())
    {
      for (String sub : entry.getValue())
      {
        String line = getLine(elements, entry.getKey(), sub);
        if (!lines.contains(line))
        {
          lines.add(line);
        }
      }
    }
    return asString(lines);
  }

  private static String getLine(Map<String, List<String>> elements, String element, String sub)
  {
    StringBuilder line = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : elements.entrySet())
    {
      if (line == null)
      {
        line = new StringBuilder();
      }
      else
      {
        line.append(DELIMITER);
      }
      if (entry.getKey().equals(element))
      {
        line.append(sub);
      }
      else
      {
        line.append(entry.getValue().get(0)); // appends the first 
      }
    }
    return line.toString();
  }

  private static String asString(List<String> lines)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    for (String line : lines)
    {
      if (sb == null)
      {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
      }
      else
      {
        sb.append(NEWLINE);
      }
      sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

And the test being:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getDataSet1()
{
  Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
  List<String> subsetA = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "a1", "a2", "a3" } );
  List<String> subsetB = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "b1", "b2" } );
  List<String> subsetC = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "c1", "c2", "c3" } );
  map.put("A", subsetA);
  map.put("B", subsetB);
  map.put("C", subsetC);
  return map;
}

@Test
public void testPrintSubsets()
{
  Map<String, List<String>> elements = getDataSet1();
  String output = SubsetPrinter.printSubsets(elements);
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b1, c1
a3, b1, c1
a1, b2, c1
a1, b1, c2
a1, b1, c3
```

Answer (score 1):

Formalizing your problem :

This can be mapped to multi-stage graphs.Just googled for a [diagrammatic illustration  online of mult-stage graphs :](http://www.gateguru.org/algorithms/multistage_graphs.pdf)  What you are trying to do is print all the paths from the super-source 'S' to the super sink 'T'. You might want to read up on the same. This is also related to the [Network Flow problem](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow),if you are interested further.